# Countdown timer vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I need a timer of the kind:

[image]

It should be repeated every month (depending on how many days in the month)

Found the code but it doesn't do what is required

```
<div>
 <countdown :endtime="endtime" />
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/neyriks/pen/YzQXrpq?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be your own component or are you happy to use 3rd party?

Looks like this package will do the trick https://fengyuanchen.github.io/vue-countdown/

Comment: I need own component :(